# Сброс полей при формировании новый ссылки

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть контроллер, по POST запросу он принимает информацию с формы и сохраняет в БД (формируется новая ссылка), далее, хочу сделать возможность редактировать эту информацию, но все, что было в форме- сбрасывается. Как сделать возможность дальнейшего редактирования?

Пример: изначально страница доступна по адресу `localhost:8090`, я вношу в поля информацию, после сохранения ссылка имеет вид `localhost:8090/TTTTTTTT`, и все поля пустые, а нужно, чтобы были заполнены как до сохранения.

**Код контроллера:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    public PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String savedPost(@RequestParam String title,
                            @RequestParam String username,
                            @RequestParam String story) {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setUsername(username);
        post.setStory(story);
        postService.add(post);

        return "redirect:/" + post.getURI();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{URI}")
    public String getPost(@PathVariable String URI, Model model){
        Post post = postService.loadPostByID(URI);
        model.addAttribute("title", post.getTitle());
        model.addAttribute("username", post.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("story", post.getStory());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Сама форма:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Ght</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="story" rows="3" placeholder="Your story..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">PUBLISH</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используйте вместо html какой-либо шаблонизатор, чтобы подставлять переданные из контроллера значения в поля формы.

Answer (score 0):

В вашей форме есть только вариант для ввода данных. Если нужно редактировать в качестве проверок на ошибки перед сохранением в бд добавляйте условия проверки либо на фронте либо на бэке (паттерны и тд).
Если нужно редактировать уже введенные и полученные из базы значения, их нужно подставлять в поля, для этого используйте JS

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере вы уже добавили атрибуты в модель для того чтобы их можно было рендерить во вью. Теперь вы можете использовать EL для получения аттрибутов.

```
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="${title}">
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" value="${username}">
<textarea class="form-control" name="story" rows="3" placeholder="Your story..." value="${story}"></textarea>
```

---

Предполагается, что у вас настроет вью резолвер для рендеринга JSP и/или JSTL. О вью резолверах можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html).

Comment: вот чего не пойму. у меня на форму повешено срабатывание на пост метод, а как сделать так, чтобы еще и на гет срабатывал?

Comment: Это еще зачем? Если на формупрописать гет, тогда тогда надо менять мапинг.